# Onclick in dropdown toggle is not working

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, toggle

I have this toggle-dropdown and I am trying to call a function `read();` upon clicking the dropdown. It is not working, I have tried using `ondrop`, `onchange` and others..

```
        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" onclick="read();">
            <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
            <span class="badge">
                <%=unread%>
            </span>
        </a>
```

Comment: Please add javascript which you have used?

Comment: can u provide us the read function.. or your complete code for find the reason

Comment: I have figured out my problem. I just forgot to add script tags. Thank you, anyway!